# display html detail page of an object using thymeleaf spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i have a spring boot application with thymeleaf for rendering the page.  the problem i am facing is i can not seem to be able to display the object details in the dom.

i am not using an iterator here.  i am simply clicking on a product and using that products id to display all the details in a redirected page here are the details

here is the get on the server

http://localhost:8080/product/details?id=1020

what calls the  http://localhost:8080/product/details?id=1020

is this other thymeleaf page which has a list or page of products; and clicking on one product which obviously has an id would start the process

```
<div class="container">
        
            <div data-th-each="p : ${page.content}">
                <div><input hidden="hidden" th:value="*{p.id}"></div>
                <div th:each="image : ${p.images[0]}">
                    <a th:href="@{/product/details?id=} + ${p.id}">
                        <img th:alt="${image.name}"
                             th:src="@{'/images/upload-dir/'}+${p.id}+'/'+${image.name}"/></a>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <a th:utext="${p.name}" **th:href="@{/product/details?id=} + ${p.id}"**></a>  <---- this is calling the new local host
                    <h1>$<span
                            th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(p.price, 0 , 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"></span>
                    </h1>
                    <form th:action="@{/shoppingCart/addItem}" method="post">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary">
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart cart-spacing"></i>Add to Cart
                        </button>
                    </form> 
       
      </nav>
    </div>
```

here is the thymeleaf page

```
<div th:object="${product}">
    <form th:action="@{/shoppingCart/add}" method="post">
        <input hidden="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
        <div class="row"> 
            <h4 th:text="${name}"></h4>

            <p th:text="${modelNumber}"></p>

            <p th:text="${serialNumber}"></p>  
         
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart cart-spacing"></i>Add to Cart
            </button>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <p th:utext="${#strings.abbreviate(description, 300)}"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

here is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String details(@PathParam("id") Long id, Model model) { 

        Optional<Product> product = productQueryService.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("product", product); 

        return "product/details";
    }
```

the service

```
public Optional<Product> findOne(Long id) {
        return productRepository.findOne(id);
    }
```

and my repository

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT p from Product p where p.id = ?1")
    Optional<Product> findOne(Long id);
```

does anyone know what seems to be the problem?  i am getting a null object; eventhough the @PathParam("id") has a value.. the service, controller, repository seem to be working fine.  i am able to get the data from the db for product.  but the product is not passing back to the dom.

thanks

[image]

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be going about this the wrong way, or I don't understand your question correctly.

If I'm correct, when you click on a product, you want the page that opens to be a page containing information about the product.

This is what I will do in thymeleaf:

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="" th:href="@{/product/details/{id}(id=${product.id})}">
        <h4 th:text="${name}"></h4>

        <p th:text="${modelNumber}"></p>

        <p th:text="${serialNumber}"></p>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart cart-spacing"></i>Add to Cart
        </button>
    </a>
    <hr/>
    <p th:utext="${#strings.abbreviate(description, 300)}"></p>
</div>
```

The controller looks okay, you can change it to use path variable or edit the code above to use request params

Edit:

I edited a past project to use the same links as yours, and I used the format you used in the a tag, Intellij showed a red line immediately. I changed the th:href to this and it worked:

`"@{/product/details(id=${p.id}}"`

And the controller looks like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String details(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) {
        Optional<Product> product = productQueryService.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        return "product/details";
    }
```

Comment: i see what you have but this is not solving my problem.  for clarity, i added more thymeleaf code from the first view that would call the new localhost i mentioned.  your answer could be in this th:href="@{/product/details/{id}(id=${product.id})} im going to embed this in the page that calls the details page

Comment: What's the error you're getting? What is being showed when you go to the product details page?

Comment: the id is passing to the service i can see it in debug; but i am for some reason not able to pass the product back to the detail page .. i put a pic of the detail.html page showing null values